# Why is evince duplicated as Comic Books in Ubuntu Software?

Tags: 16.04, updates, software-center, pdf, evince

I installed an update to evince, and also saw an update for 'Comic Books' which appeared identical. I installed both updates, then realized I'm not using this PC for comic books and uninstalled that software. Then I found that evince was also uninstalled!

Then when I tried to reinstall evince, Ubuntu Software required me to login to (log into?) Ubuntu One 'to install snaps' before I could authenticate to install the software.

I'm tempted to call anything I dislike a bug, but why is 'evince' duplicated in Ubuntu Software as 'Comic Books' as if it were a separate application, even to the point of having to click 'Install' twice in the Updates tab?

Please see the embedded screenshot for an illustration of how Ubuntu Software is apparently listing evince twice.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what 'Comic Books' is, but if you can figure the package name you can open a terminal and type: sudo apt show [name of package here]. This will show you the dependencies and probably evince will be there.

Comment: It appears that evince is more than a dependency of Comic Books, because reinstalling evince also apparently reinstalled Comic Books. I have edited the original post to include a screenshot: The description for 'Comic Books' is a description for evince.

Comment: I have found 'Document Viewer' -- yet another listing of evince -- in Ubuntu Software listing 'Comic Books' as an add-on. However, removing it apparently does not work.