# How to repair evince / Document Viewer after Comic Books uninstall and evince reinstall?

Tags: unity, package-management, launcher, pdf, evince

[Previously I discussed uninstalling Comic Books and then reinstalling evince](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983332/why-is-evince-duplicated-as-comic-books-in-ubuntu-software). Now the software is broken: It will not load. 'evince' doesn't show up in the Launcher; I must search 'Document Viewer', and it will not load either from the Launcher or from right-click opening a PDF file, even though the evince logo is displayed on the PDF files. The program box appears on the toolbar, flashes a bit as if it is loading, and then vanishes.

How do I fix it? It was working prior to installing the latest upgrade to evince and Comic Books and uninstalling Comic Books and reinstalling evince. The only thing I know to do is backup my files and reinstall the entire system, which seems excessive.

Answer (score 0):

I opened Ubuntu Software, searched 'document viewer', clicked 'Install' even though evince was already installed (i.e. had the button 'Remove' available), shut down the computer, and booted back up. I can now open PDF files in Document Viewer.